# Printing characters from a given sequence till a certain range only. How to do this in Python?

Tags: python, character

I have a file in which I have a sequence of characters. I want to read the second line of that file and want to read the characters of that line to a certain range only.

I tried this code, however, it is only printing specific characters from both lines. And not printing the range.

```
with open ("irumfas.fas", "r") as file:
    first_chars = [line[1] for line in file if not line.isspace()]
    print(first_chars)
```

Can anyone help in this regard? How can I give a range?
Below is mentioned the sequence that I want to print.But I want to start printing the characters from the second line of the sequence till a certain range only.

> IRUMSEQ
> ATTATAAAATTAAAATTATATCCAATGAATTCAATTAAATTAAATTAAAGAATTCAATAATATACCCCGGGGGGATCCAATTAAAAGCTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: I want to start printing characters from line two only (which is starting from A). So, how should I do that and make it print from a file?

Comment: Note that all answers (so far) read the entire file. This can be inefficient if the file is very large. Instead, you can just call [`file.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file#io.IOBase.readline) twice. Or even a combination of `readline()` once, then [`read(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file#io.IOBase.readline) where x is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach can be used.
Consider the file contains

```
RANDOMTEXTSAMPLE
SAMPLERANDOMTEXT
RANDOMSAMPLETEXT
```

```
with open('sampleText.txt') as sampleText:
    content = sampleText.read()
    content = content.split("\n")[1]
    content = content[:6]
    print(content)
```

Output will be

```
SAMPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the line[1] in the file as you would slice a list.

**You were very close:**

```
end = 6 # number of characters
with open ("irumfas.fas", "r") as file:
    first_chars = [line[1][:end] for line in file if not line.isspace()]
    print(first_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
with open("irumfas.fas", "r") as file:
    second_line = file.readlines()[1]
    print(second_line[0:9])
```

`readlines()` will give you a list of the lines -- which we index to get only the 2nd line. Your existing code will iterate over *all* the lines (which is not what you want).

As for extracting a certain range, you can use list slices to *select* the range of characters you want from that line -- in the example above, its the first 10.